# jq filter from long nested result

Tags: json, jq

I want to extract only the mac fields from this result with jq JSON processor:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
      0,
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "mac": "11:22:33:44:55:66",
            "noise": 0,
            "mesh llid": 0,
            "connected_time": 165947,
            "rx": {
              "rate": 6000
            },
            "mesh local PS": "",
            "tx": {
              "rate": 6000
            },
            "signal": -63
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
      0,
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "mac": "11:22:33:44:55:66",
            "noise": -105,
            "mesh llid": 0,
            "connected_time": 106975,
            "rx": {
              "rate": 650000
            },
            "mesh local PS": "",
            "tx": {
              "rate": 360000
            },
            "inactive": 40
          },
          {
            "mac": "11:22:33:44:55:66",
            "noise": -105,
            "mesh llid": 0,
            "connected_time": 20813,
            "rx": {
              "rate": 24000
            },
            "mesh local PS": "",
            "tx": {
              "rate": 6000
            },
            "inactive": 230
          },
          {
            "mac": "11:22:33:44:55:66",
            "noise": -105,
            "mesh llid": 0,
            "connected_time": 2106,
            "rx": {
              "rate": 24000
            },
            "mesh local PS": "",
            "tx": {
              "rate": 6000
            },
            "inactive": 240
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I use `jq '.[].result'`, I dont know how to select the next results field. I used the online service [jq play](https://jqplay.org/) - but without luck. Everything I try to add, results in a error.

Best will be if I get only the mac addresses, without json formatting - if possible - as an result. But I can also later use egrep/awk and others to extract..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `..` and so may not be exactly what you want, but it has the merit of simplicity:

```
jq -r '.. | objects | .mac // empty' input.json
11:22:33:44:55:66
11:22:33:44:55:66
11:22:33:44:55:66
11:22:33:44:55:66
```